# Select2 does not escape HTML or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I have a select2 field that searches for existing tags and if the tag does not currently exist you can enter a new one.

If I use select2 with default options just for selecting items from a select html tag it escapes code fine. For example something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tagselect').each(function() {
        var placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var saved = $(this).data('saved');
        $(this).select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
    });
});
```

But something in my JS seems to brake it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tagselect').each(function() {
        var placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var saved = $(this).data('saved');
        $(this).select2({
            tags: true,
            width: '400px',
            placeholder: placeholder,
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            initSelection : function(element, callback){
                saved && callback(saved);
            },
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data:    function(term) { return { q: term }; },
                results: function(data) { return { results: data }; }
            },
            createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
                if ($(data).filter(function() {
                    return this.name.localeCompare(term)===0;
                }).length===0) {
                    return { id: term, name: term };
                }
            },
            multiple: true,
            formatResult:    function(item, page){ return item.name; },
            formatSelection: function(item, page){ return item.name; }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check "select2" options tags type.

First example tags type is Array.

```
tags:["red", "green", "blue"]
```

Second example tags type is boolean.

```
tags: true
```

Can select2 accept type of array or boolean???

Comment: yes. My functionality works perfectly fine. The only issue here is the escaping. I think it has something to do with formatResult and formatSelection.